# How to sort the items in an array to match the order that it appears in another array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, refactoring

I want to grab the ratings from movies in the database and return an array of unique ratings, sorted in the following order:

```
G PG PG-13 R NC-17
```

A plain `Array#sort` wasn't enough:

```
["PG-13", "PG", "NC-17", "G", "R"].sort
# => ["G", "NC-17", "PG", "PG-13", "R"]
```

The following code gives me what I want, but seems like there's a better way to write it not having to use `delete` and `<<`. Any ideas would be appreciated.

```
class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.all_ratings
    allRatings = []
    Movie.all.each do |movie|
      unless allRatings.include?(movie.rating)
        allRatings << movie.rating
      end
    end
    if allRatings.include?("NC-17")
      allRatings.sort!
      allRatings.delete("NC-17")
      allRatings << "NC-17"
      return allRatings
    else
      return allRatings.sort
    end
  end
end
```

---

UPDATE:
Using Sergio's tip, I was able to refactor the code. If anyone has some other ideas, I'd appreciate the feedback.

```
class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base

  def self.all_ratings
    allRatings = []
    Movie.all.each do |movie|
      unless allRatings.include?(movie.rating)
        allRatings << movie.rating
      end
    end
    allRatings.sort_by! {|t| t == 'NC-17' ? 'ZZZ' : t}
  end
end
```

---

UPDATE:
Using ByScripts tip, this code works well and is very concise. I had to upgrade from Rails 3.1.0 to Rails 3.2.8 to get the `pluck` method. Looks like it was introduced in 3.2.1.

I also had to add `.sort` to get the desired output.

```
class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base

  def self.all_ratings
    all_ratings = Movie.pluck(:rating).uniq.sort# don't retrieve unnecessary datas
    all_ratings << all_ratings.delete('NC-17') # directly inject NC-17 at the end if exists
    all_ratings.compact # remove nil values
  end

end
```

Comment: you forgot to put a ! after compact :)

Comment: And it's better to use `Movie.uniq.pluck(:rating)` instead of `Movie.pluck(:rating).uniq`.  The second one returns a list of array whose size is the same as the number of movies on your db before you call uniq on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this small trick

```
sorted = ["PG-13", "PG", "NC-17", "G", "R"].sort_by {|t| t == 'NC-17' ? 'ZZZ' : t }

sorted # => ["G", "PG", "PG-13", "R", "NC-17"]
```

Basically, for sorting purposes, you substitute "NC-17" with a "ZZZ" which sorts last.

Comment: Thanks Sergio, just the type of approach I was looking for

Answer (score 2):

That should works :

```
def self.all_ratings
  all_ratings = Movies.order(:rating).pluck(:rating).uniq # don't retrieve unnecessary datas
  all_ratings << all_rating.delete('NC-17') # directly inject NC-17 at the end if exists
  all_ratings.compact # remove nil values
end
```

You can also do `Movies.uniq.pluck(:rating)`

That does a `SELECT DISTINCT` query (where `pluck.uniq` filters the array). Don't know if there is a performance impact (maybe a lower memory footprint ?).

Anyway, both should works the same.

Comment: Very cool. The code I was using was Rails 3.1.0, which didn't have `pluck` method. Upgraded to Rails 3.2.8 and works great. The only change I had to make was to the first line, I had to add a `.sort` after `.uniq`, otherwise the output was `["G", "R", "PG-13", "PG", "NC-17"]`, order of uniq ratings in DB. Thanks!

Comment: Indeed. Updated to add the .order() (placed it after Movies, so the DB does the order)

Answer (score 1):

I like Sergio's trick, but if you're looking for a simpler version of your original code that still does have `delete` and `<<`, try this

```
def sort(ratings)
  ratings.sort!
  return ratings unless ratings.include?("NC-17")

  ratings.delete("NC-17")

  ratings << "NC-17"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base
  RatingOrder = %w[G PG PG-13 R NC-17]
  def self.all_ratings
    RatingOrder & Movie.all.map(&:rating)
  end
end
```